# How to find and replace forwardslashes with colons in bash script?

Tags: macos, bash, applescript

What I'm trying right now:

```
dir=$(pwd)
dir=${$dir//\//:}
```

But this isn't working for some reason.

The whole point of this is to convert a bash path to an applescript path, without hardcoding the path in there.

I'm essentially trying to do the opposite of this:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4938/how-to-change-applescript-path-to-a-terminal-style-path

Comment: You can use in the internal $PWD variable instead of executing the pwd command.

Answer (score 5):

Your syntax is just a bit off, don't use `$` on the variable *within* the `${}` construct:

```
dir=${dir//\//:}
```